# How to pass a prop in to a child component on click - Vue2

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Idea behind the code is to make a child component active, when i click on it in a parent vue.

Parent vue file:

```
<PackageItem
  v-for="pack in packagesData"
  :key="pack.id"
  @click.native="selectPackageItem(pack.id, pack.humanLabel, pack.humanPrice, pack.index)"
>
```

Child component:

```
props: {
  selected: Boolean
},

data () {
  return {
    selected: selected
  }
},
```

How can i send `selected` prop on click to a child component? If i set it this way:

```
<PackageItem
  :selected="true"
  @click.native="selectPackageItem(pack.id, pack.humanLabel, pack.humanPrice, pack.index)"
>
```

It would make all items selected to `true`, i want to set it on click only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like:

```
<PackageItem
  v-for="pack in packagesData"
  :key="pack.id"
  @click.native="
    selectPackageItem(pack.id, pack.humanLabel, pack.humanPrice, pack.index)"
  :selected="selected[pack.id]"
>
```

Where `selectedPackageItem` method will set the selected package:

```
selectPackageItem(packId, packLabel, packPrice, packIndex) {
    this.$set('selected', packId, true)
```

Or, if you want to toggle between true and false on click:

```
this.$set('selected', packId, !this.selected[packId])
```

In the data option, you should just have:

```
selected: []
```

---

Also, in your child component the following code is not required:

```
/* REMOVE
 data () {
   return {
     selected: selected
   }
 },
*/
```

When you want to use selected props inside script, you just need to use `this.selected` and inside the template just use `selected`.

Comment: Is it achievable without an array in selected variable?

Comment: Are you sure that i can remove `selected` from a child component? My purpose was to make each package item toggleable individually from active to a false state.

Comment: Yes. That's not needed. Just props  is okay.

Comment: `this.$set` makes `selected` available in a child component? I couldn't find info in the vue docs about this moment.

Comment: No. you're passing `:selected=""` that what is being passed in the child component. this.$set is used for updating selected value.

Answer (score 1):

You can control the selection from the parent component by defining an array to store selected ids and a function to check selection.

```
data(){
    return {
        ...
        selected: []
    }
},
methods: {
    isSelected(id){
        return this.selected.indexOf(id) > -1;
    }
}
```

Then in your click method, push the id of the clicked item.

```
// Stub for `selectPackageItem` method
if(this.isSelected(id)){
    // Maybe unselect?
} else {
    this.selected.push(id);
}
```

Now you template becomes:-

```
<PackageItem v-for="pack in packagesData" :selected="isSelected(pack.id)" :key="pack.id" @click.native="selectPackageItem(pack.id, pack.humanLabel, pack.humanPrice, pack.index)">
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with a more elegant solution:

```
<PackageItem
  v-for="pack in packagesData"
  :key="pack.id"
  :selected="selectedPackages(pack.index)"
  @click.native="selectPackageItem(pack.id, pack.humanLabel, pack.humanPrice, pack.index)"
>
```

Then added a method to check selected packages in an array:

```
selectedPackages (index) {
  let packages = this.packages
  let selected = packages.some(p => p.index === index)
  return selected
}
```

`selectedPackages` returns a boolean value. `this.packages` is an array with active packages (clicked), that contains a lot of information besides `ID` and `index`. With `.some` i am getting `true` or `false` value, if clicked item's `index` is exact the same with the one in array (`this.packages`).